# Actor supervised by BackoffSupervisor loses stashed messages after restart

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-supervision

I have an actor with stash usage. Sometimes, when it crashes, it loses all stashed messages. I found that it depends on what supervision logic I use.

I wrote a simple example.

An actor with the stash:

```
case object WrongMessage
case object TestMessage
case object InitialMessage

class TestActor extends Actor with Stash {
  override def receive: Receive = uninitializedReceive

  def uninitializedReceive: Receive = {
    case TestMessage =>
      println(s"stash test message")
      stash()

    case WrongMessage =>
      println(s"wrong message")
      throw new Throwable("wrong message")

    case InitialMessage =>
      println(s"initial message")
      context.become(initializedReceive)
      unstashAll()
  }

  def initializedReceive: Receive = {
    case TestMessage =>
      println(s"test message")
  }
}
```

In the following code, `TestActor` **never** receives stashed `TestMessage`:

```
object Test1 extends App {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  val actorRef = system.actorOf(BackoffSupervisor.props(Backoff.onFailure(
      Props[TestActor], "TestActor", 1 seconds, 1 seconds, 0
  ).withSupervisorStrategy(OneForOneStrategy()({
    case _ => SupervisorStrategy.Restart
  }))))
  actorRef ! TestMessage
  Thread.sleep(5000L)
  actorRef ! WrongMessage
  Thread.sleep(5000L)
  actorRef ! InitialMessage
}
```

But this code works well:

```
class SupervisionActor extends Actor {
  val testActorRef: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[TestActor])

  override def supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy()({
    case _ => SupervisorStrategy.Restart
  })

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case message => testActorRef forward message
  }
}

object Test2 extends App {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  val actorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SupervisionActor]))
  actorRef ! TestMessage
  Thread.sleep(5000L)
  actorRef ! WrongMessage
  Thread.sleep(5000L)
  actorRef ! InitialMessage
}
```

I looked into sources and found that actor supervision uses
[LocalActorRef.restart](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorRef.scala#L402) method which backed by [system dispatcher logic](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/dungeon/Dispatch.scala#L131), but `BackoffSupervisor` simply [creates a new actor](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/BackoffSupervisor.scala#L389) after [termination of the old one](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/BackoffSupervisor.scala#L346). Is there any way to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure one can make `restart` under `BackoffSupervisor` properly send stashed messages without some custom re-implementation effort.

As you've already pointed out that `BackoffSupervisor` does its own `restart` that bypasses the standard actor lifecycle.  In fact, it's explicitly noted in the [BackoffOnRestartSupervisor](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/BackoffOnRestartSupervisor.scala) source code:

> Whatever the final Directive is, we will translate all Restarts to our
>   own Restarts, which involves stopping the child.

In case you haven't read about this [reported issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/23406), it has a relevant discussion re: problem with [Backoff.onFailure](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/pattern/Backoff$.html#onFailure(childProps:akka.actor.Props,childName:String,minBackoff:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,maxBackoff:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,randomFactor:Double):akka.pattern.BackoffOptions).

[Backoff.onStop](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/pattern/Backoff$.html#onStop(childProps:akka.actor.Props,childName:String,minBackoff:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,maxBackoff:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,randomFactor:Double):akka.pattern.BackoffOptions) would also give the wanted BackoffSupervisor feature, but unfortunately it has its own use cases and won't be triggered by an exception.

Comment: Thank you for links. It seems like stashing just doesn't work with BackoffSupervisor.